# python.h not found when trying to install gevent-socketio

Tags: python, django, gevent-socketio

here is my error when I try to install gevent-socketio

> Installing collected packages: gevent, greenlet
>    Running setup.py install for gevent
>    building 'gevent.core' extension
>    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes >-fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CHECK_ENABLE=0 -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 >-DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev >-I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
>      gevent/gevent.core.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>      compilation terminated.
>      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>      Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;**file**='/var/www/bleu/build/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-_kv6Fy-record/install-record.txt:
>      running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'gevent.core' extension
>
> gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC > -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CHECK_ENABLE=0 -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.core.o
>
> gevent/gevent.core.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Have you an idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install the **Development Package(s)**:

**CentOS/RHEL**::

```
yum install python-devel
```

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
apt-get install python-dev
```